# How do I get an element from shadow DOM in Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

could someone please explain to me how to get an element from shadow DOM in `Selenium4` in `Python`? I want to element.click() to Accept the cookies - but I fail at the very first step!

I've tried `driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#shadow_host')`
... `driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#shadow_root')`

Every time `"no such element: Unable to locate element"`.

Bye

Michael

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get element's `shadow-root`, you should first get it's host and then get property `shadowRoot`.

In your case, host tag is `cmm-cookie-banner`. So, you get this element and then execute JS script on it.

```py
def get_shadow_root(element):
    return driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)

shadow_host = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'cmm-cookie-banner')
button = get_shadow_root(shadow_host).find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[data-test=handle-accept-all-button]')
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not know that I have to address the non-shadow-root-element first.