# Visible not detected with Selenium in Python for element in a shadow root

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I would like to find with Selenium the following `button` element:

```
<button class="walla-button__button walla-button__button--full-width walla-button__button--large walla-button__button--primary" role="button" type="submit" part="button">
    <div class="walla-button__children-container" part="children-container">
        <slot name="left-icon"></slot>
        <span>Acceder a Wallapop</span>
        <slot name="right-component"></slot>
    </div>
</button>
```

This element is in a popup sign-in window together with other elements that Selenium does find, but the problematic element is also direct child to a shadow root, unlike the elements that Selenium can find. Enclose one element that can be found and the button that is problematic:

Input:

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='signin-email']")))
```

Output:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement
(session="0f58f81835cb803c3785a19702d01945",
element="f.267C3EB8F2845581DDDFF3F95FF7DD1E.d.ABF640D3BAB43142CFC70C05BF2CACE6.e.124")>
```

Input:

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//button[@class='walla-button__button walla-button__button--full-width walla-button__button--large walla-button__button--primary' and @type='submit']")))
```

Output:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------- TimeoutException Traceback (most recent call last) Cell In[214], line 1
----> 1 wait.until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//button[@class='walla-button__button walla-button__button--full-width walla-button__button--large
walla-button__button--primary' and @type='submit']")))

File
~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py:105,
in WebDriverWait.until(self, method, message)
    103     if time.monotonic() > end_time:
    104         break
--> 105 raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)

TimeoutException: Message: 
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//button[@class='walla-button__button walla-button__button--full-width walla-button__button--large walla-button__button--primary' and @type='submit']")))
```

Help on how to find and click that button appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why [a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code/HTML as text and properly format it instead. This includes the full error message.

Comment: Did you check to see if the button is in an IFRAME or shadow-root? Add that info to your question.

Comment: @JeffC, Thanks for the feedback! the element is indeed in a shadow-root. Updated the question accordingly.

Comment: So now that you know it's an a shadow-root, you should be able to get access to it.

Comment: @JeffC, thanks again! In case anyone stumbles upon this question, I followed the example shown at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77105233/how-do-i-get-an-element-from-shadow-dom-in-selenium-in-python