how to handle shadow dom
it was working and click on the verify you are human in the CF 'Under Attack' and the CF Captcha,
 if sb.is_element_visible("//div/iframe"):
    sb.is_element_present("#challenge-stage > div > label > span")
    current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M:%S %p")
    print(colorama.Fore.LIGHTWHITE_EX + f"{current_time} - CF Mark Element found.")
    sb.switch_to_frame("//div/iframe")
    try:
        sb.execute_script('document.querySelector("input").focus()')
    except:
        pass
    sb.disconnect()
    # Move the mouse to the center of the screen before pressing space
    pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False
    pyautogui.press(" ")
    sb.driver.reconnect(4)
    sb.driver.switch_to.default_content()
else:
    current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M:%S %p")
    print(colorama.Fore.LIGHTCYAN_EX + f"{current_time} - CF Mark Element not found. Switching back...")
    sb.driver.switch_to.default_content()

Now the iframe not fond because they add the CF code in shadow dom

How to handle ? #shadow-root (closed) to reach the iframe and the elements

Does this post help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/77105233/2532408

no sir not work for me
